# window.load is not working with turbolinks

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

i have written this code in

**application.html.erb**

```
<div class="preloader"> 
 <div class="rounder"></div>
</div>

 <div id="main"> 
  <div class="container"> 
   <div class="row"> 
    <%= render partial: 'shared/profile' %> 
     <div class="col-md-9"> 
      <%= yield %> 
      <%= render partial: 'shared/footer' %> 
     </div> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
 </div>
```

**application.js**

> ```
>     $(window).load(function () {
>         $('.preloader').delay(800).fadeOut('slow');
>      });
> ```

the problem with this is , when i remove

> //= require turbolinks
>   this works fine but with turbolinks its not working. even though i also tried `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'` , but its not working also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
    $('.preloader').delay(800).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: not working . actually its work first time when page loads but with any link when i went to any other page it doesn't work, for example i have one link on contact us page on which link is to redirect to home page, but when i click on that link preloader runs infinte time and page doesn't load.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one also

```
function preloader(){
   $('.preloader').delay(800).fadeOut('slow');
}
$(preloader);
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", preloader);
```

Comment: actually its work first time when page loads but with any link when i went to any other page it doesn't work, for example i have one link on contact us page on which link is to redirect to home page, but when i click on that link preloader runs infinte time and page doesn't load

Comment: @Anand can u post yr `.preload` html block ? where ist located i think u have a page and html issue.

Comment: .preload block is written inside application.html.erb
here is my code.

     <div class="preloader">
        <div class="rounder"></div>   </div>
        <div id="main">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <%= render partial: 'shared/profile' %>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <%= yield %>
                <%= render partial: 'shared/footer' %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>`

Comment: <div class="preloader">
        <div class="rounder"></div>   </div>
        <div id="main">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <%= render partial: 'shared/profile' %>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <%= yield %>
                <%= render partial: 'shared/footer' %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div